# Django Rest framework getting all foreign key data in parent object

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a family model like below

```
class Family(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    monthly_contribution = models.FloatField(default=0)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + f' ({self.address})'
```

I have a Parishioner model like below

```
class Parishioner(models.Model):

    def _age(self):
        return date.today().year - self.dob.year

    """Parishioner model"""
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=1000, default=get_next_parishoner_id)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dob = models.DateField()
    age = property(_age)
    GENDER_CHOICES = [("Male", "Male"), ("Female", "Female"), ("Other", "Other")]
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    fathers_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    mothers_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    baptism_certificate = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=upload_image)
    marriage_certificate = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=upload_image)
    family = models.ForeignKey(Family, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    role = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

This is my Family viewset

```
class FamilyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Family.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FamilySerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

This is my Parishioner viewset

```
class ParishionerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Parishioner.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ParishionerSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

This is my Family serializer

```
class FamilySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = ParishionerSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Family
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'address', 'monthly_contribution','members', 'enabled')
        read_only_fields = ('id','members',)
```

This is my Parishioner serializer

```
class ParishionerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Parishioner
        fields = ('id','first_name', 'last_name', 'dob', 'age', 'gender', 'address', 'fathers_name', 'mothers_name', 'baptism_certificate', 'marriage_certificate', 'family', 'role')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

So relationship is One to Many.
Parishioner can exist in One Family.
One Family has many members(Parishioners).

When I call my `/api/family/` I'm getting below Response

```
[
    {
        "id": 13,
        "name": "Mendis Family",
        "address": "No 48, Katukurunda",
        "monthly_contribution": 50.0,
        "enabled": false
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Perera Family",
        "address": "No 40",
        "monthly_contribution": 20.0,
        "enabled": true
    }
]
```

Is it possible to get all members too within that response in a members property (Array) ?
like below ?

```
[
        {
            "id": 13,
            "name": "Mendis Family",
            "address": "No 48, Katukurunda",
            "monthly_contribution": 50.0,
            "members":[{"id":"1", "first_name":"John",...etc},
                        {"id":"2", "first_name":"Jane",...etc}],
            "enabled": false
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "name": "Perera Family",
            "address": "No 40",
            "monthly_contribution": 20.0,
             "members":[{"id":"3", "first_name":"Jackie",...etc},
                        {"id":"4", "first_name":"Jockie",...etc}]
            "enabled": true
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your FamilySerializer.

```
members = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_members(self, obj):
    queryset = Parishioner.objects.filter(family=obj.id)
    serializer = ParishionerSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    return serializer.data
```